# How to write changes to database when within a begin/commit/rollback block

Tags: php, database, postgresql

We have implemented a DB begin/commit/rollback system where you can have a begin begin/commit in code anywhere and if there when you do a begin/commit in a particular place, you are within another begin/commit block, then it will only do a commit when you are back at the first level of begin. This is done using a static variable which just keeps a count of which level of begin/commit block you are in. Every time you encounter a begin, if the counter is 1 then a BEGIN is sent to the DB and counter is incremented. If counter is more than one then only increments the counter. Similarly, if a commit is requested, then the counter is decremented and only in the case where the counter is 1, a real COMMIT command is sent to the database.

Firstly, any thoughts on this way of doing this? This has worked very well for us for a long time. However, we have come to a situation now where we do need to save some data to the database irrespective of where we are in terms of begin/commit level.

How do people handle this in general? Also what thoughts on the way we are handling the multi-level begin/commit?

BTW we are doing this in PHP with a postgres database.

Thanks
Ziad

Comment: Your best bet is to create a separate transaction (or connection, depending on implementation) from which to run the insert you wish to guarantee.

Comment: You cannot do that within a single connection/transaction. For embedded transactions, see `SAVEPOINT`s http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-savepoint.html

Comment: This functionality is generally called "autonomous transactions" and does not exist in PostgreSQL. The workaround is always to open a new connection. Consider the dblink module for a server-side implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe is pretty much how JTA (the Java Transaction API) manages declarative transaction scopes in EJB3. You mark methods as requiring a transaction, and if no transaction is open one is begun. Transaction end is delineated by the end of the method that began the transaction.

> However, we have come to a situation now where we do need to save some data to the database irrespective of where we are in terms of begin/commit level.

You will need a new connection one way or the other, because PostgreSQL does not support *autonomous transactions* - suspending a transaction, doing something else, and resuming the transaction, or just committing only part of the transaction.

JTA handles this by making a new JDBC connection to the server behind the scenes when you have a method that says it `REQUIRES_NEW`. The method requires that even if there's an open transaction that transaction is suspended and a new one is started instead. As PostgreSQL doesn't support that, JTA emulates it.

You'll want to do the same, and I strongly suggest you study how JTA does things. For a Java API, it's surprisingly non-awful.

---

A PHP-specific factor: PHP likes to cache connections, so multiple connection attempts will usually return the same connection handle. Use the `PGSQL_CONNECT_FORCE_NEW` option to `pg_connect`, or (preferably) use PDO, which doesn't return cached connections unless you explicitly tell it to with `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT`.

---

BTW, you might not be aware of savepoints.

If you see a nested `BEGIN`, you can change that to `SAVEPOINT [savepointname]`. A `ROLLBACK` becomes `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT [savepointname]`. `COMMIT` is just `RELEASE SAVEPOINT [savepointname]` - i.e. "I don't expect to have to roll back to this, and if the outer transaction commits then mine should to".

Savepoints aren't free, though, so you should only use them when there's a chance you might actually need to roll back a subtransaction.

You can't commit a subtransaction in a way that's preserved if the outer transaction rolls back, but they're still very handy when you're running things that might `ERROR` as part of big, expensive transactions.

Comment: I forgot to mention that we figured that we need a new connection so that the transaction on that connection is separate and tried that but it didn't work. I think the issue was what you pointed out about PHP caching the connections so we were in effect getting the same connection. Thanks for pointing that out, it is working now. Thanks to everyone who commented.

Comment: @Ziad Glad to help. You should look at moving to PDO. It's maintained (unlike  the legacy postgres stuff) and less broken. Not to say "not broken" as this is still PHP, but a lot less broken - for example, `bytea` support works properly.